# Initializing my new AD-HOC profile for testing Push Notifications on Production

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning, code-signing-certificate

I want to test Push Notifications in iOS production version before I publish it. I understand I cant sign it with distribution profile ,only `AD-HOC profiles`.

So I created an `AD-HOC` profile, selected the right `bundle`, selected my device that I work with and created a new profile. I downloaded it and after that I select it in:

**Provisioning Profile -> Release - AD-HOC-NEW**

**Provisioning Profile -> Debug (Any SDK, Any iOS SDK) are with Automatic.**

It compiles and installed on my device through Xcode but notification don't come.

When I try to change `Debug` settings also to my new profile I'm getting an error :

*"No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identify(i.e certificate and private key pair) were found.
No codesigning identities (i.e certificate and private key pairs) that much the provision profile specified in your build settings ("AD-HOC-New") were found. Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the member center."*

I press "**Fix Issue**" but It dont fix it...

What could be the problem?

Comment: You are not getting the notification.

Are you first sure that the issue does not come from the server side ? Are you sure your .pem file is correct for instance?

Comment: Yes, because already app in the market on that production Server is using that certificate,the same that I use in my AD-HOC

Comment: Did you deploy it over the air / as a real ad hoc binary, or just by building it on your phone straight from xCode ?
In the second case, it will not work from my own experience.

Comment: I compile it with `AD-HOC` profile and install it straight from xCode on my device

Comment: Ok then I think that are you are not doing a real ad hoc deployment, you app is still requesting a token for the sandbox (debug/local) mode.

You should give it a try with a true ad-hoc deployement. For instance, you can dot it through Product->Archive (make sure that archiving use your Release profile in the Edit Schemes view), export the IPA and put it on your device with a drag&drop in iTunes.

Comment: @RomainDorange You right,only installing it from iTunes fixed this problem. write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should install your binary not straight xCode but as a real over-the-air/ ad hoc deployement.

The consequence is that your application will request at launch not a token from the sandbox environment but from the production one, and this will match your certificate (which is a production one too).

You do a real ad-hoc deployement both by installing your .ipa through iTunes, or by using a solution such as Testfligt.